# Issues in import database in android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, import

Im new to android development. Now im trying to use sqlite db. I created a database sqlite file using sqlite manager.
I have tried the following code, it works fine in emulator , but if I took release in device the app crashes ie,it shows an alert message  The application CheckMobileForDatabase has stopped unexpectedly, my sdk version is 2.2(8)

```
 private void StoreDatabase() {
 File DbFile=new File("data/data/com.sqldemo/databases/idua1");
 if(DbFile.exists())
 {
     System.out.println("file already exist ,No need to Create");
 }
 else
 {
     try 
     {
         DbFile.createNewFile();
         System.out.println("File Created successfully");
         InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("idua1.sqlite");
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DbFile);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length=0;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer))>0)
            {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
         System.out.println("File succesfully placed on sdcard");
            //Close the streams
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            is.close();
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }    
   }
```

Comment: Please post the logcat showing the error.

Comment: above code work fine in emulator,but i release that project it works fine in emulator , the app crashes,it shows an alert message The application CheckMobileForDatabase has stopped unexpectedly.ple solve this problem

Comment: So run it with the phone plugged in and then grab the logcat when it crashes and post it.  We can't do anything without seeing *why* it's failing, as there is nothing obvious in the code you posted.

Comment: any other changes my code ple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your logcat, this is just shooting in the dark.

You could try checking the existence of the file another way:

```
private static boolean checkDataBase(String dbname) {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    boolean exist = false;
    try {
        String db = MAIN_DB_PATH + dbname;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.v("db log", "database does't exist");
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        exist = true;
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return exist;
}
```

And then run another method to copy the db if it doesn't exist:

```
private static void copyDataBase(String dbname) throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = mCtx.getAssets().open(dbname);
    String outFileName = MAIN_DB_PATH + dbname;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its may be due to previous version of database stored in your android device, try deleting previous db from  your device or change version of database in code so that onupgrade will be called